# Change size of hyperlinked text

Tags: html

How to change size  of the text "FAA/ATC Plan" to 1 or 2
I don't want to use css .

```
       <tr><td> <a href = ""  onclick="Popup.open({url:'Plan.pdf',width:800,height:500,resizable:'yes', separateWindow:true});">FAA/ATC Plan</a></td></tr>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: You should try jQuery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, you can use HTML font tag.

Why not use CSS? You can use inline styles if you don't want an external CSS file. Both options like so:

```html
 <tr><td> <a href = ""  onclick="Popup.open({url:'Plan.pdf',width:800,height:500,resizable:'yes', separateWindow:true});">FAA/ATC Plan original</a></td></tr>
 
 <br>
 
 <tr><td> <font size="2"><a href = ""  onclick="Popup.open({url:'Plan.pdf',width:800,height:500,resizable:'yes', separateWindow:true});">FAA/ATC Plan with HTML tag</a></font></td></tr>
 
 <br>
 
 <tr><td> <a style="font-size: 6px" href = ""  onclick="Popup.open({url:'Plan.pdf',width:800,height:500,resizable:'yes', separateWindow:true});">FAA/ATC Plan with inline style</a></td></tr>
```

What do you actually mean with "size of text to 1 or 2"? Pixels? That would be way to small as you can see from my example...